# Insert values from one table into another in which data type is same but column's name is different

Tags: sql, insert, insert-into

I have two tables.

Both tables have same columns, but the columns are named differently.

first table has columns:

```
|ID_pk|Name
```

and has only unique [ID] (one-to-one)

second table has columns:

```
|SerialNumber|FullLegalName|PassportNumber_fk|
```

and has one-to-many relationship between [SerialNumber] and [PassportNumber]

[ID] and [SerialNumber] columns do not have matching values.

I need to insert all [ID] and [Name] values to the second table into [SerialNumber] and [FullLegalName] with their respective [PassportNumber(s)].

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
update tbl2
set tbl2.SerialNumber= tbl1.id,
    tbl2.FullLegalName = tbl1.Name 

from tbl1, tbl2
where tbl2.PassportNumber = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like these.

but the column property of first and second table must equal.

```
update SecondTable 
set SerialNumber = ft.ID,
   FullLegalName = ft.Name
from FirstTable as ft 
   inner join SecondTable as st on ft.Id = st.PassportNumber_fk_ColumneName
   inner join ThirdTable as tt on st.PassportNumber_fk_ColumneName = tt.PassportNumber_pk_ColumneName
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any matching values in the first and second table, so I"m not sure what this join is supposed to do. May be I better use where Not Exists?

Comment: The question can be closed. I developed another solution CTE. But also having difficulties with it. I'll post a link to a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801035/update-with-cte-does-not-recognizes-column-names-in-the-set-clause