# Update with CTE does not recognize column names in the set clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I need to update an existing table with data from another. My CTE is giving me correct result, but when I'm trying to update with the CTE SSMS complains on

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

or Invalid column names at the lines below:

```
set cm.Action.Identifier_fk = ID
set cm.ActionRequestedAction = Action
set cm.Action.apartment_fk = apartment_fk
```

This is the code:

```
Use DB;
GO

with CTE (ID,Action,Identifier_fk,apartment_fk) AS 

(select a.ID, a.Action, b.Identifier_fk, m.apartment_fk 
from Project.AllSent a (nolock) 
    left outer join cm.Action b (nolock) on a.ID=b.Identifier_fk
    left Outer Join csv.Matching m (nolock) on m.Identifier_fk = a.ID
    left outer join csv.Apartment p (nolock) on m.apartment_fk=p.apartment_pk
    where b.Identifier_fk is NULL) 

update cm.Action 
set cm.Action.Identifier_fk = ID
set cm.Action.RequestedAction = Action
set cm.Action.apartment_fk = apartment_fk

    from CTE c
    JOIN Project.AllSent t (nolock) on t.ID=c.ID;
```

Comment: what is `cm.Action` in the `update` query?

Comment: cm - is a schema, Action - is a table.

Comment: It's been a while since I have used SQL Server, but can you have multiple `SET` calls in one updated? Don't you just separate them with commas?

Comment: I guess you are right, It handles just one per execution. I've already tried executing them one at a time, but I'm still prompting to the same issue.

Comment: No, the syntax to update multiple columns is `set col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3`

Answer (score 0):

The correct `update` statement has only one `set`.  Also, you have no `cm` in the `from` clause.  I'm going to propose getting rid of the CTE:

```
update b
    set Identifier_fk = a.ID,
        Action.RequestedAction = a.Action,
        apartment_fk = mm.apartment_fk
    from Project.AllSent a (nolock) left join
         cm.Action b (nolock)
         on a.ID = b.Identifier_fk left join
         csv.Matching m (nolock)
         on m.Identifier_fk = a.ID left join
         csv.Apartment p (nolock)
         on m.apartment_fk = p.apartment_pk
    where b.Identifier_fk is NULL;
```

I don't think the final `join` is necessary.

Comment: I think so too, I's not necessary.

Comment: I do see [cm] in the From clause in the join. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Not sue why, but this updates 0 rows... Any idea? (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: I see no `cm`.  All the aliases should refer to tables in the `from` clause.

Comment: @enigma6205 . . . You query is using `left join` to the table being updated.  That doesn't really make sense.  Either `b` should be the first table in the `from` clause or the first join should be an `inner join`.

Comment: I'm using left join on the query because table A and table B has 0 matching values. Example table A has id [1,2,3,4], table B has id [5,6,7,12]. I need all not matching IDs from table A to be loaded to table B.

Comment: @enigma6205 . . . But you are updating `B`.  If there is no matching record in `A`, then nothing is updated.